# C# Unity: What's the difference between calling another class's function directly vs. calling the function by subscribing to an event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In game development (Unity C#) there was always a question in my head about the best method or best approach to call a function from another class, there are two methods that i use here:

**METHOD 1**

> Making the function `DoSomething` public in class 1 and call it from
>   class 2

Class 1:

```
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour{

    public static Class1 instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    //The function we want to call
    public function DoSomething(){

        Debug.Log("Done something!");

    }

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Class2 : MonoBehaviour{

    private Class1 _class1;

    private void start(){
        _class1 = Class1.instance;
    }

    public function SomeFunction(){

        //Calling the function
        _class1.DoSomething();

    }

}
```

**METHOD 2**

> Creating an `event` in class 2 and subscribing to this event in class 1, this way the function will get called when we trigger the event in class 2

Class 1:

```
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour{


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Class2.OnSomeEvent += DoSomething;
    }


    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Class2.OnSomeEvent -= DoSomething;
    }

    //The function we want to call
    private function DoSomething(){

        Debug.Log("Done something!");

    }

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Class2 : MonoBehaviour{

    public static event Action OnSomeEvent = delegate {};

    public function SomeFunction(){

        OnSomeEvent();

    }

}
```

**What's the difference between the two methods and which one has the best functionality and performance?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second solution with the event, `Class2` doesn't need to know anything about `Class1`. Maybe even several other objects may subscribe this event or maybe none. `Class2` presenting the event, may even belong to a library written at a time when the subscriber `Class1` didn't exist.

Example: You are creating a control `MySuperButton` which looks much better than the standard buttons. This button will be used in different places and call different click-handlers. So, when writing the button code, you don't know the methods to be called when the button will be clicked. You just raise a Click-event and you are done.

Performance differences can be neglected in most cases.

[The C# Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/) guide says:

> - Events enable a class or object to notify other classes or objects when something of interest occurs.
> - The publisher determines when an event is raised; the subscribers determine what action is taken in response to the event.

So basically, you get a better decoupling of concerns and also an inversion of the dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The performance depends on the use case. Let's say you want to run some method on a class once the player health is below a certain value. One option is to check on every **Update** whether it's time to do that. That however would be inefficient. A better option would be to subscribe to an event which is triggered only when the health is changed and do the health check there instead.

Besides that, it's an extra tool for developing project architecture. Instead of mixing code together, you can have one class that deals with informing others when some **X** thing happens and others can listen to that event.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any performance differences. Using the Event system can be much more code efficient/convenient. Suppose you want something in the program happens where you want DoSomething to stop firing, simply unsubscribe to the event.

```
Class2.OnSomeEvent -= DoSomething;
```

Another scenario, suppose that your senior dev wants Class3.SomethingMore and Class4.AnotherThing to happen too. Rather than chaining them to the DoSomething method they also can just subscribe to the event with multicasting.

```
 // in Class 3 OnEnable
 Class2.OnSomeEvent += SomethingMore;

 // in Class 4 OnEnable
 Class2.OnSomeEvent += AnotherThing;
```

Now OnSomeEvent will fire all three events. The delegate system makes your code much more readable, modular and easier to debug as your program becomes larger and complex. You can subscribe methods to important events in your game rather than making long, hard-to-read method call chains that are difficult to go back and make changes to. Generally, Unity is designed to be as modular as possible with its Component system, and a delegate event system is a way to also make method calls modular. You could also say there is an added bonus of classes not needing references to other classes and permissions for their methods when the other classes subscribe to the event.

To add one more example, lets say you didn't use the event system and right now you had different classes that periodically called.

```
Class1.DoSomething();
```

Your senior dev tells you that whenever DoSomething() is called, SomethingMore() and AnotherThing() need to be called. You can look through the code and try to find every place where DoSomething() is called and add two lines after SomethingMore() and AnotherThing() and make sure the classes calling have references to Class3 and Class4. Another option is to add references to these classes in Class1 and in the end of the DoSomething() method add SomethingMore() and AnotherThing(). The issue with this if later on your team figures out that DoSomething() should be called in certain cases by itself without SomethingMore() and AnotherThing(), now your code is going to start getting ugly.

Finally, lets say you are instantiating 'Bug' enemies that will Swarm() when the queen commands them to. There is no consistent amount of 'Bug' enemies as some spawn randomly and are destroyed by the player. Its much easier in the 'Bug' script for each bug to subscribe to the 'SwarmCommand' event of the queen than it is in the Queen script when 'SwarmCommand' is called to find references to each and every bug and call the bug 'Swarm()' (You would need to call FindObjectsWithTag or keep an up-to-date array of all the Bug GameObjects which would have some costs attached).